# Facebook api is giving Bad Request as response

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I tried to post (message and image) to facebook wall using Graph api.

I can able to post message and images for some time,after I am continuesly getting Bad Request as response.

IS there any restriction from facebook about wall posts using api.

Why this is occuring?

please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are Graph API rate limits to help avoid abuse. The limits are not published but usually if you're hitting these limits then you're likely doing something wrong. You could work at backing off posting if you encounter these errors.